# Convergence of square sum of normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Given a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with distribution $N(0,1)$, for what does the sequence

$${Y_n = \frac{X_1^2+ \ldots + X_n^2}{(X_1 - 1)^2 + \ldots + (X_n - 1)^2} \ , n \in \mathbb{N} \ ,
}$$
converges to? I saw a similar argument with the LLN being used for the geometric mean but can't see how to apply it in this case...

Comment: This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) to the wiki on chi-squared distributions might be useful

Answer (score 3):

I guess, one just has to expand the fraction with n. Then

$$Y_n = \frac{X_1^2 + \ldots + X_n^2}{n} \frac{n}{(X_1-1)^2 + \ldots + (X_n-1)^2},$$

and the regular LLN can be applied for both factors separately. Afterwards the continuous mapping theorem ensures that the product of the two limits is the actual limit. Should be 1/2.

Comment: That's the kind of trick that makes me feel dumb after I see it. I'm gonna try again from here, thanks.

Comment: The almost sure convergence of the two dimensional random vectors follows from the almost sure convergence of the components, right?

Comment: For almost sure convergence we have the same rules as for standard convergence of real vectors, yes.